# UFT How to find a web table depending on web element

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to find the web table below the web element

For example in that image
 **Parity Relationship: Instant Dry Milk** is the Web Element (Just the web element - Browser-page-web element)

I want to find the table name below that web element

Comment: What is the table name in this case? Is it `Instant Dry Milk` or something else? If that is the case, why don't you use the `innertext` property of the webelement?

Comment: Attached Object properties of web element and web table below that web element

Comment: I want to find the table name below that web element. So in this case I should find the table name as qty_1_0001111088466. (Table name is dynamic)

Comment: You have to find some correlation between the webelement and its corresponding webtable. I am able to see some sort of correlation between them by their `xpath` property's value. But to be sure, I will be needing the xpath values of the 1st webelement and its corresponding webtable too.Can you post the spy screenshots for them to or just tell me their xpath values?

Comment: Attached web table and web element xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use this `XPath` as part of object description to identify the table.

```
.//legend[contains(.,'Parity Relationship:') and contains(.,'Instant Dry Milk')]/following-sibling::table
```

Once you get the table, use **`GetROProperty`** to retrieve the **`name`** property value.

I have created sample HTML page and here is the screenshot of working XPath:

[image]

Comment: Glad to help... :)

Answer (score 1):

UFT allows you to nest objects and will then search for the nested object only under the nesting object.

You can see more details in this [blog post](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-and-Testing-Blog/Understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-HP-Unified-Functional/ba-p/247123) (search for *"WebElement(s)"*).

So you can have something like this:

```
Browser("B").Page("P").WebElement("Parity Relationship: Instant Dry Milk").WebTable("T")
```